# Is it possible to parameter in Date from in Date parameter for BI publisher?

Tags: bi-publisher

Is it possible to assign a parameter value for date from in date parameter?

under date parameter we have date from and date to option to define the range of date to be selected in the calendar. I want to pass a parameter with date type to the  date from option .is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Go to your data mode in the tab 'parameters' find your name variable which refers in date from and choose date as data type.

[image]

Hope this helps..

Comment: can u please explain with some pic..am new to Bi..thanks for your help

Comment: if i provide default date say 01-01-2001 for p_date_from .can i pass the :p_date_from to another date parameter for range(date from,date to option)

Comment: yes you can do this,click the green insert button and add a new p_date_to parameter with tha same data type